# Создание отступов у всех кнопок, которые находятся на Activity

Tags: android, activity, checkbox, android-button

У меня есть Activity, и в нём больше десяти кнопок, которые находятся в друг под другом.
Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы при долгом зажатии одной из этих кнопок, у всех кнопок появлялся внешний отступ слева.
В эти отступы нужно добавить CheckBox, напротив каждой кнопки.
Я выбираю некоторые кнопки, которые хочу удалить. Отмечаю CheckBox, которые находятся напротив кнопок, которые я хочу удалить. Нажимаю на кнопку "удалить", и кнопки, чекбоксы которых были отмечены, удаляются.
Это должно работать примерно так же, как и удаление сообщений в Вконтаке, только у меня не сообщения, а кнопки.
Первая функция:

```
private void carFunc() {
    final RelativeLayout mainLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.mainmain);
    ImageButton imageView = new ImageButton(Main2Activity.this);
    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.car);
    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
    final RelativeLayout.LayoutParams imageViewLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(450, 150);
    imageView.setLayoutParams(imageViewLayoutParams);
    imageView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    imageViewLayoutParams.setMargins(15,10,0,0);
    imageView.setId(Integer.parseInt("25"));

    imageView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            imageViewLayoutParams.setMargins(70,10,0,0);


            CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox(Main2Activity.this);
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams checkParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams
                    (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            checkParams.setMargins(10, 55, 0, 0);
            mainLayout.addView(checkBox, checkParams);
            return true;
        }
    });
    imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent int46 = new Intent(Main2Activity.this, car.class);
            startActivity(int46);
        }
    });


    SharedPreferences sharedPref = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
    editor.putInt("int", 25);
    editor.apply();

    mainLayout.addView(imageView);
}
```

Вторая функция:

```
private void dogeFunc() {
    RelativeLayout mainLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.mainmain);
    ImageButton imageView1 = new ImageButton(Main2Activity.this);
    imageView1.setImageResource(R.drawable.doge);
    imageView1.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams imageViewLayoutParams1 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(450, 150);
    imageView1.setLayoutParams(imageViewLayoutParams1);
    imageView1.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    imageViewLayoutParams1.setMargins(15,10,0,0);
    imageView1.setId(Integer.parseInt("31"));

    SharedPreferences sharedPref = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
    editor.putInt("int", 26);
    editor.apply();

    imageView1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent int461 = new Intent(Main2Activity.this, doge.class);
            startActivity(int461);
        }
    });


    mainLayout.addView(imageView1);

}
```

Comment: добавтье код, что удалось сделать самостоятельно или в чем конкретно проблема с реализацией. Если это какое то ТЗ на разработку, то писать его нужно не здесь, а на какой-нибудь фриланс-бирже. Здесь не пишут код по заданию, за плюсики, а помогают решить проблемы с имеющимся кодом, в основном

Comment: Хорошо, завтра добавлю код.

Comment: @pavlofff отредактировал

Comment: ну и что там? Не код не работает? Работает не так? В чем проблема, кроме того, что "нужно сделать так"?

Comment: @Эникейщик Я не знаю, как сделать так, чтобы если я зажимаю кнопку, то у всех одновременно появлялся отступ справа

Comment: @Эникейщик Согласен, что для этого сайта, вопрос, скорее всего не подходит.

Comment: @Эникейщик Но я не знаю, где ещё пытаться найти ответ. Весь интернет перерыл.

Comment: onLongClick в первом файле работает?

Comment: @Эникейщик Да, зажимаю кнопку, появляется отступ у первой кнопки, и в эту кнопку добавляется CheckBox.

Comment: Ну вот, нужно добавить этот слушатель к каждой кнопке.

Comment: @Эникейщик Да, но проблема в том, что это работает только на одну кнопку. Мне нужно, чтобы я зажимал одну кнопку, и отступ появлялся у всех кнопок, которые находятся на acitivty